# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection created at Driver and accesible from Reducer in a mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hbase

In a mapreduce job I need to get some rows from HBase table with Get.
I assume this is going to be pretty fast. Even doing that Get from HBase within a reducer.
But what I wanted to avoid is creating a connection inside the reducer. And, instead of that, create a connection

```
connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
```

in the Driver and put it somewhere, so it's accessible from the reducer.

I see that in org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration object, you can only put strings or string arrays, by setParameter method.

Is there any other way to set the HBase Connection just once, so it is accesible from reduce phase?
Thanks!

Comment: You should understand that Reducers run in prallel if specified. Instead, why wouldn't you read the required chunk of data in driver and put into cache for reducer/mapper use?

Comment: That's what I finally did. Thanks a lot.